# Unable to do the transform animation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Unable to get `Animated` to work. I am adding a button style and `Animated.View` in the container. So when I `pressIn` I want the `Animated.View` to shrink to .5 and when on `pressOut` want it to come back to 1. I set the `this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1)` on `componentWillMount` itself.  My code is below:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Animated, Easing, Image,
         TouchableWithoutFeedback, View} from 'react-native';

class MyAnim extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.handlePressIn = this.handlePressIn.bind(this);
      this.handlePressOut = this.handlePressOut.bind(this);
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
  }

  handlePressIn() {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        to: .5
    }).start()
  }
  handlePressOut() {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        to: 1,
        friction: 3,
        tension: 40
    }).start()
  }

  render() {
    const animatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ scale: this.animatedValue }]
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
          onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
        >
          <Animated.View style={[styles.button, animatedStyle]}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Press Me</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:'#333', width:100, height:50, marginBottom:10,
    justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'
  },
  buttonText:{
    color:'#fff'
  },
});

export default MyAnim;
```

I'm trying a simple spring animation. The error is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I want the button to to transform to size .5 on pressIn and back to 1 on pressOut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `toValue` instead of `to` as mentioned in the latest [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#spring)

> Tracks velocity state to create fluid motions as the **toValue** updates, and can be chained together.

Also as mentioned in their [SpringAnimation.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bc8e42a5e6a2c0161d5820e62047f5103b94a33f/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/SpringAnimation.js#L24) config

```
 toValue: number | AnimatedValue | {x: number, y: number} | AnimatedValueXY,

handlePressIn() {
        Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
            toValue: .5
        }).start()
    }

handlePressOut() {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        toValue: 1,
        friction: 3,
        tension: 40
    }).start()
  }
```